# Making a raw dictionary sane

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a dict brought in from a csv: `{'0ca6f08e': '1111', '89b2e9ab': '2222', '0c2e5b6d': '3333', '07287d73': '4444'}`

and what is needed is something like:
`{'id' :'0ca6f08e', 'thing': '1111'}, {'id': '89b2e9ab', 'thing': '2222'}, {'id: '0c2e5b6d', 'thing': '3333'}`

This is to bring order to the dict so I can operate later with sanity.  I'm not clear on how to take a csv like:

```
0ca6f08e,1111
89b2e9ab,2222
0c2e5b6d,3333
```

an inject the keys for sanity and later use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a list comprehension to solve this:

```
>>> original = {'0ca6f08e': '1111', '89b2e9ab': '2222', '0c2e5b6d': '3333', '07287d73': '4444'}
>>> parsed = [{'id': key, 'thing': value} for key, value in a.items()]
>>> parsed
[{'thing': '1111', 'id': '0ca6f08e'}, {'thing': '2222', 'id': '89b2e9ab'}, {'thing': '3333', 'id': '0c2e5b6d'}, {'thing'
: '4444', 'id': '07287d73'}]
```

We're essentially grabbing each key and corresponding value in the original dict, and converting it into a list of dicts.

Note that it may be cleaner to just use the `items` method of a dict to grab the key and the value directly, and loop over that:

```
>>> original.items()
[('0ca6f08e', '1111'), ('89b2e9ab', '2222'), ('0c2e5b6d', '3333'), ('07287d73', '4444')]
```

Comment: cheers.  I kept the original dict creation and added this afterwards to create the sub-dicts and I'm good.

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading the file for the first time, you can fix the results like this:

```
with open('foo.csv') as f:
   for line in f:
      lines = [{'id': a, 'thing': b} for a,b in line.split(',')]
```

If you want to fix the results from the dictionary:

```
lines = [{'id': a, 'thing': b} for a,b in big_dict.iteritems()]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the csv module's [DictReader](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) to read the csv file.

Here is an example:

```
import csv
with open('example.csv') as csvfile:
    for csv_dict in csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=["id", "thing"])
        # Now you can use the csv_dict as a normal dictionary
        print csv_dict["id"]
```

Comment: I get the notion but the syntax errored on me and I wasn't seeing why.  I'd rather do this and import "clean".